# Java regex to match quoted string with embedded escaped quote

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I need help with a regex for matching a quoted string that could have an embedded escaped quote.

For example, given string `"'John\'s bike'"`. The basic pattern i was starting with, `"'[^']*'"`, and expanding it to negate case of embedded escaped quotes using lookbehind doesn't work: `"'((?<\\)[^'])*'"`.

Anyone has idea?

The string could be a series of quoted strings, e.g., "'John\'s bike', 'Mary\'s hat', 'my shoes'", and i want to tokenize each of the quoted substrings separately.

Comment: You have not demonstrated to us what your problem is sufficiently. Why can't you just use "'.*'" which captures your single test case. Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/zV0lI5/1) Do you not wish to capture `John\'s bike'?

Comment: Once you add the double quote as part of the regex `"' .. '"` you introduce a double delimiter. Not really too good. By double delim, I mean a delimiter that consists of 2 characters, that have open/close specific context. Like should `"'hello\'"` world match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accept any character between quotes which is

- preceded by `\`
- not `'`.

So your regex can look like:

`'(\\.|[^'])*'`

which in Java should look like `"'(\\\\.|[^'])*'"` (to create `\` literal in regex we need to escape it like `\\` but same rules applies in String literals so we need to escape these two `\` again which finally gives us `"\\\\"`)

Demo based on your example:

```
String input = "'John\\'s bike', 'Mary\\'s hat', 'my shoes'";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(\\\\.|[^'])*'");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
'John\'s bike'
'Mary\'s hat'
'my shoes'
```

Comment: Why didn't i think of that? I was making it more complicated by explicitly looking for escaped backlash. Thank you!

Comment: this fails for `\\"`. The regex `"(\\\\[^\\\\]|[^\"])*"` should do the trick.

Comment: @mvallebr What do you mean by *fails*? What ``\\"`` represents? IMO it represents escaped ``\`` and not escaped `"` in which case we can consider that `"` as opening\closing quote (I am assuming that in your case `"` is quotation symbol, not `'`).

Comment: The original question said nothing about escaping back slashes. I never thought of it as a requirement. The requirement, for me, was solely escape quotes, nothing more.

Comment: @mvallebr In that case your text probably doesn't contains ``\`` as simple character (like in paths `c:\foo\bar`). Generally if we start using ``\`` as "escaping" character then we agree that it became *metacharacter* which other tools sees as *start of sequence which should be treated specially* (so they can't simply "print" that ``\`` as it was normal character). Anyway if your text would contain ``\`` as normal characters at some point you would end up with text like ``foo\`` which should be written in quote. But how would you do it?

Comment: If there is no way to escape ``\`` then you would need to write it as ``'foo\'``. But that would represent `foo` and escaped `'`. So we need *some* way of escaping ``\`` and most tools use another ``\`` to escape it (like ``\\``) since ``\`` is already treated as escaping sequence. While in OP question we this mechanism is not explicitly mentioned it exist in great amount of cases. That is why I used in my regex ``\.`` which accept escaping of any character, instead of ``\[^\]`` which doesn't consider ``\`` as ever being escaped.

Comment: I think there is a way to escape - we could escape only `\"` and not touch any other backslash. The regex I suggest would do it, right?

Comment: So how exactly should ``foo\`` be placed at the end of quote? If we write is as `"...foo\"` it will represent `foo` and escaped `"` so ``\`` disappears (which is NOT what we want).